# Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android

I made a new class named "Question" (Question.java)
By calling it in the main activity for creation of an array, it is saying Can not resolve symbol. The code is as follows.
In the activity

```
private Question [] mQuestionBank = new Question[] {
        new Question (R.string.question_punjab,true),
        new Question (R.string.question_cat, true),
        new Question (R.string.question_wear, false),
        new Question (R.string.question_iPhone, true),
        new Question (R.string.question_shahrukh,false)
};
```

The question class is as follows

```
public class Question {
private int mTextResId;
private boolean mAnswerTrue;

public int getTextResId() {
    return mTextResId;
}

public void setTextResId(int textResId) {
    mTextResId = textResId;
}

public boolean isAnswerTrue() {
    return mAnswerTrue;
}

public void setAnswerTrue(boolean answerTrue) {
    mAnswerTrue = answerTrue;
}

public Question(int textResiD, boolean AnswerTrue) {

    mTextResId = textResId;
    mAnswerTrue = answerTrue;
}
}
```

Comment: your constructor has a typo "textResiD" vs. "textResId"

Comment: And answerTrue vs AnswerTrue

Answer (score 0):

Just Change you (as mentioned in comments too)

```
public Question(int textResiD, boolean AnswerTrue) {

    mTextResId = textResId;
    mAnswerTrue = answerTrue;
}
```

into

```
 public Question(int textResId, boolean answerTrue) {

        mTextResId = textResId;
        mAnswerTrue = answerTrue;
    }
```